# Flutter showTextInputDialog usage

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter and I'm stuck here.
I'm trying to use Dialog box to get user input but I don't know how to process the data after submitting the value.

I'm using `adaptive_dialog: ^1.0.0` dependency here.

```dart
child: ListTile(
    title: Text('Change Age'),
    onTap: () {
         showTextInputDialog(
               context: context,
               title: 'Enter your Age!',
               textFields: [
                     DialogTextField(
                           keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                           hintText: '18',
                     )
               ],
                     okLabel: 'Submit',
                     cancelLabel: 'Cancel',
          );
    },
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialog box to get user input

```
import 'package:adaptive_dialog/adaptive_dialog.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int age = 0;
  TextEditingController ageController = new TextEditingController();
  Future<void> _displayTextInputDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          ageController.text="";
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Enter your age'),
            content: TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  age = int.parse(value);
                });
              },
              controller: ageController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "18"),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              // ignore: deprecated_member_use
              FlatButton(
                //color: Colors.red,
                //textColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text('CANCEL'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  });
                },
              ),
              // ignore: deprecated_member_use
              FlatButton(
                //color: Colors.green,
                //textColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    // age = int.parse(value);
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Change Age'),
              onTap: () {
                _displayTextInputDialog(context);
              },
            ),
            Text(age.toString())
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this worked and I changed the FlatButton with TextButton, it removed the deprecated warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.then` and the `index` of the textField to get the value

```
showTextInputDialog(
context: context,
title: "Enter your Age!",
message: 'Age here',
okLabel: "Submit",
cancelLabel: "Cancel",
barrierDismissible: false,
textFields: [
  const DialogTextField(
     keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
     hintText: '18',
  )
],
).then((value) {
  return debugPrint(value![0]);
    }
);
```